# IOS stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString coming back null

Tags: ios, string, exception

I've been banging my head against the wall on this, I must be missing something.  This code is called just after I base64 encode some encrypted text.  At the point where I call NSLog signature is always valid.   However sometimes the rest works great and other times removePlus or finalSig come back null.  Also I'm using Xcode 4.5, ios6 and I have ARC enabled for the project.   I feel like maybe something is getting auto released before I want it to, or something like that.   If anyone has any ideas any help is appreciated.

```
// Get the data out of the context
char *outputBuffer;
long outputLength = BIO_get_mem_data(context, &outputBuffer);

NSMutableString *signature = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[signature appendString:[NSMutableString stringWithCString:outputBuffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"Base64 Pre Encoded: %@", signature);

signature = [[signature stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] mutableCopy];
NSMutableString *removePlus = [[signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"] mutableCopy];
NSString *finalSig = [removePlus stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];

//now we create the url request portion
NSMutableString *variables = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

//set the variables we're going
[variables appendString:finalSig];
```

Comment: Why are you creating mutable strings, since you don't use/modify them?

Comment: Yep, and it should be noted that `mutableCopy` returns a retained object (pre-ARC).

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping your code for the following, as I imagine it will show you exactly where your problem is:

```
// Get the data out of the context
char *outputBuffer;
long outputLength = BIO_get_mem_data(context, &outputBuffer);

outputBuffer[outputLength] = '\0';
if(outputLength != strlen(outputBuffer)) NSLog(@"SOMETHING VERY WRONG");

NSString * signature = [NSString stringWithCString:outputBuffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"Base64 Pre Encoded: %@", signature);

signature = [[signature stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Base64 Post Encoded: %@", signature);

signature = [signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
NSLog(@"Base64 Remove '+': %@", signature);

signature = [removePlus stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
NSLog(@"Base64 Remove '=': %@", signature);

//now we create the url request portion
NSMutableString *variables = [NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:signature];

…

//set the variables we're going
[variables appendString:finalSig];
```

Comment: Yep, in general, break your operations down into simple steps and log the results of each step.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that NSString * signature = [NSString stringWithCString:outputBuffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]; requires a null terminated string and my string was not.  Anyway this was a more effective way to create the string:

```
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ variables UTF8String ] length: [ variables length ] ];
```